# Rspec allow block to run

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have some code that is run within a changed directory.

I want to mock the directory change in Rspec, while still allow the useful code within to run.

```
Dir.chdir(directory) do
  useful_code
end
```

In psudo-code I'd like to be able to write:

`allow(Dir).to_receive(:chdir).and_run_block`

Comment: Why test the code in place? Why not extract an object and give the `useful_code` a testable home of its own?

Answer (score 1):

`allow(Dir).to receive(:chdir).and_yield`

`and_yield(args)` allows you to define what args will be inputs to the block for that method.

Docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/yielding